# VueAwesomeSwiper - How to remove the gray lazy background?

Tags: css, vue.js, swiper.js

I am using `vue-awesome-swiper` component to create a nice images, the problem is when the next image comes in, a noisy gray overlay showing when loading the image.

I've tried to set lazy to false in my configuration but without avail.

Here is my swiper component content:

```
<div class="swiper-lazy c-slider__img" :data-background="require(`~/assets/images/${slide.image}`)">
    <div class="c-slider__content h-container">
        <div class="c-slider__content-block">
        <h2 class="c-slider__heading">{{ slide.heading }}</h2>
        <p class="c-slider__text">{{ slide.content }}</p>
        <n-link
            :to="localePath({ path: slide.url })"
            class="c-slider__more"
        >
            Read More
            <span class="c-slider__more-icon">
            <app-icon
                name="icon-arrow"
                :width="21"
                :height="8"
                color="#fff"
            />
            </span>
        </n-link>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div>
</div>

<script>
import AppIcon from '~/components/UI/AppIcon'

export default {
components: {
    AppIcon
},
props: {
    slides: {
    type: Array,
    default: () => []
    }
},
data: () => ({
    swiperOption: {
    preloadImages: false,
    lazy: true,
    loop: true,
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true
    },
    effect: 'fade',
    fadeEffect: {
        crossFade: true
    },
    autoplay: {
        delay: 5000
    }
    }
})
}
</script>
```